# OpenNMS configure SNMP output

Tags: opennms

First of all sorry if this is not the best place to put my question, but I searched everywhere and I think it can be someone out there that had the same problem.

I am using OpenNMS to collect data from my network via SNMP.

My problem is that the folder structure of the result. Instead of having the IP has the internal ID of the OpenNMS

For example, the output is:

**/var/opennms/rrd/snmp/1**

but I need it to be:

**/var/opennms/rrd/snmp/10.10.10.10**

Has anyone else had the same problem?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a problem, per se, but is a feature of the node-centric nature of OpenNMS.  To dynamically access your SNMP data (via a script, for example), you would first need to query the OpenNMS database, and find the node id associated with a given IP.  This could be a problem, however, as it is possible to have more than one node with the same IP address.  What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I know this is not a problem. Since the ICMP data is organized by the "primary" IP I was wondering if the same is not possible with the data  collected by SNMP. As you said I can access this information in the database. However it is not interesting making queries to the database, when there is a solution of putting directly the IP on the name folder. But thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 0):

The default for opennms is to store by node ID. it is possible to change this to store by foreignSource by changing org.opennms.rrd.storeByForeignSource setting in $OPENNMS_HOME/etc/opennms.properties to true

however, this will only affect where data is stored for nodes that are provisioned.  you would need to ensure you provision your nodes with a foreign ID that makes sense to your environment.  Foreign ID does not need to be a number, but can be any string that provides you uniqueness for your provisioning requisition.  I'm using hostname for the foreignID in my system as that is more static than IP address.  You could use an IP address, however, as noted by @EvT it is possible to have the same IP address linked to multiple nodes, so this might not be feasable.  Also, if an IP address was to change, then your foreignID based on IP address would then be incorrect.